# Formatting DateTime in ASP.Net GridView while updating, without using c#

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview

Refer the code below:

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB" SortExpression="dob" >
                    <EditItemTemplate >
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" Width="60px" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dob", "{0:d-M-yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>

                        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox3_CalendarExtender"  runat="server" Enabled="True" Format="d-M-yyyy" TargetControlID="TextBox3">
                        </asp:CalendarExtender>

                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dob", "{0:d-M-yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

I've a DateTime column named "dob" in db. I've formatted it in "d-M-yyy" while binding.
Everything works perfect except when user updates his DOB directly from GridView.

Since, I've displayed the date  in textbox in "d-M-yyyy" format, while db server treats it as "mm-dd-yyyy" format, then problem arises when user wants to update data.

By the way, the server raises this:

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Code for Update:

```
  UpdateCommand="update family_members_info set dob=@dob  where memberID=@memberID">              
            <UpdateParameters>                                
                <asp:Parameter Name="memberID" />                   
                <asp:Parameter Name="dob" Type="DateTime" />                    
            </UpdateParameters>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we see the code where you update?

Comment: what are using to update?

Comment: Updated the code to update..

Answer (score 0):

hi use the date format as

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" Width="60px" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dob", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped to add

```
<globalization culture="cs-CZ" uiCulture="cs-CZ" />
```

tag in the web.config file.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)