# Trying to update a ASP.NET(C#) gridview datetime field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, sql-server-2012

I have gridview in asp.net connected to a sqldatasource, and I have the edit option checked. I have two fields I want to update, one named `CHECKTIME(data type datetime)` and `CHECKTYPE`. I am able to update `CHECKTYPE` with the gridview with no problems but when I try to update `CHECKTIME` it doesn't change, but instead it stays with the original values. Please help; below find the update query I'm using.

Query:

```
UPDATE CHECKINOUT SET CHECKTYPE = @CHECKTYPE, CHECKTIME = @CHECKTIME  
FROM CHECKINOUT INNER JOIN USERINFO  
ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID  
WHERE (CHECKINOUT.USERID = @USERID) AND (CHECKINOUT.trans = @trans)
```

updategridview.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TimeClockManager.aspx.cs" Inherits="TimeClockViewer.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:attConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT USERINFO.USERID, USERINFO.NAME, USERINFO.TITLE, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE FROM USERINFO INNER JOIN CHECKINOUT ON USERINFO.USERID = CHECKINOUT.USERID
WHERE ( NAME = @NAME and @NAME&lt;&gt; '-1' OR @NAME = '-1' and 1=1) AND CHECKTIME BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate + ' 23:59:00.000'" UpdateCommand="UPDATE CHECKINOUT SET CHECKTYPE = @CHECKTYPE, CHECKTIME = convert(datetime,@CHECKTIME)
FROM CHECKINOUT INNER JOIN USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID 
WHERE (CHECKINOUT.USERID = @USERID) AND (CHECKINOUT.trans = @trans)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEmployee" Name="NAME" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtBoxStartDate" Name="startDate" PropertyName="Text" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtBoxEndDate" Name="endDate" PropertyName="Text" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CHECKTYPE" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="CHECKTIME"  />
            <asp:Parameter Name="USERID" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="trans" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;Employee:
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployee" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="NAME" DataValueField="NAME" Height="40px" Width="193px" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
        <asp:ListItem Value="-1">All</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Start Date:

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxStartDate" runat="server" Width="146px"></asp:TextBox>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; End Date<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="txtBoxStartDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtBoxStartDate">
    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
    :
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxEndDate" runat="server" Width="146px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="txtBoxEndDate_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtBoxEndDate">
    </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:attConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [NAME] FROM [USERINFO] ORDER BY [NAME]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="USERID">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="USERID" HeaderText="USERID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="USERID" ReadOnly="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME" HeaderText="NAME" SortExpression="NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TITLE" HeaderText="TITLE" SortExpression="TITLE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CHECKTIME" HeaderText="CHECKTIME" SortExpression="CHECKTIME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CHECKTYPE" HeaderText="CHECKTYPE" SortExpression="CHECKTYPE" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />
    </asp:GridView>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: When updates fail with no error message, the problem is almost always the WHERE clause not being able to locate any records.   If you can get the WHERE clause to select records, you'll be able to update them.  In your case, this clause is probably failing: (CHECKINOUT.trans = @trans)

Comment: I dont think its the WHERE clause because I can update the CHECKTYPE field

Comment: Do you have two databases?   Are you updating database A but looking for the results in database B?    Or, you are updating the field to a value it is already set to.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the typical problem while trying to update a datetime filed using datasource in the gridview edit mode. 
I think the problem is the data source tries to assign the text value to the datetime field and if it fails to convert in any case (because database accepts datetime in yyyy-MM-dd format), it just ignores it.

One was of soliving this is to use the OnRowUpdating event of the grid view.
Add OnUpdating event to the GridView

```
OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
```

In the OnRowUpdating event catch the textbox value and assign it to datasource

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //Get the correct cell number of your datetime field        
    var dateTimeString = row.Cells[4].Controls[0] as TextBox;
    if (dateTimeString != null)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString.Text, out dateTime))

        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["CHECKTIME"].DefaultValue = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
}
```

However there also a other solutions like below which you can try
[Formatting DateTime in ASP.Net GridView while updating, without using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083114/formatting-datetime-in-asp-net-gridview-while-updating-without-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Did you debug to this event? Do you get the textbox and the entered values properly? Is it assigning to the data source?